# the data is not in the correct format when I fetch it from a query

Tags: r, phpmyadmin

I want to retrieve data from a table t1. The data are strings. In phpmyadmin characters are displayed correctly but when I make a query to get data, it's no longer in the correct format.

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 host = "host",
                 user = "user",
                 password = "password",
                 dbname = "database",
                 encoding = 'UTF-8')
query <- "SELECT * FROM t1"
data <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
dbDisconnect(con)
Encoding(data)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" ...
```

For exemple: I have the word: **Régie Réserve** and what i get is
**RÃ©gie RÃ©serve**

---

- **collation for the connection to the server** it's: **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**
- **database collation** was latin1_swidish_ci, i set it to utf8_general_ci. Now i have ? character.

Comment: "the data is no longer in the correct format" Well, in which format is it then?

Comment: @Roland Hello, i update my post with a exemple.

Comment: Try `encoding = 'Latin-1'`.

Comment: @andschar i get the same problem, i tried  'latin-1' too.